# Tensorflow GPU is not available with different user account Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I setup a Windows 10 environment with Cuda, cuDNN, `tensorflow-gpu` and all the necessary modules.

With my local administrator account everything is working just fine and all the check commands I run show the 2 GPUs.

However if I login with another local administrator account check commands return only CPU.

Sample command I used for my validation:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
```

Do you have any idea how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the configuration modules for Cuda, cuDNN and `tensorflow-gpu` were not installed globally for all users. You may have to do this if you want to use these modules across all Users. Otherwise, you may have to do an individual configuration for each local administrator if they have the privileges to install these modules.

Comment: It appears that tensorflow-gpu gave me an error when I installed it.
So I have to use the --user to Successfully insall it.

However this means the module is not installed for all users so I have to install it for other users then it worked fine.